# Custom Search - How to re-order the array with respect to a value within the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Lets say i have an array

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "Baburam",
    relation: "self_owner"
  },
  {
    name: "Prapti",
    relation: "grand_child"
  },
  {
    name: "Sanjay",
    relation: "son"
  },
  {
    name: "Bhagwati",
    relation: "wife"
  },
  {
    name: "maya",
    relation: "mother"
  },
]
```

I want to re-order the array with respect to specified value **relation** and this order is fixed:

1. self_owner
2. wife
3. mother
4. son
5. grand_child

How can i get such result.
What i expect is:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: "Baburam",
    relation: "self_owner"
  },
  {
    name: "Bhagwati",
    relation: "wife"
  },
  ,
  {
    name: "Sanjay",
    relation: "son"
  },
  {
    name: "maya",
    relation: "mother"
  },
  {
    name: "Prapti",
    relation: "grand_child"
  }
  
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont see an attempt

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: i did and i failed. I cant relate that mozilla example to my requirement because the array is not fixed , array's order is random

Comment: If you have a value. Search one of: Bubblesort, Insertionsort, Maxsort, Quicksort, Mergesort, Heapsort ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your order in an `array` and then sort according to `index` of the `relation` of the Object in `arr`

```js
const sortorder =['self_owner','wife','mother','son','grand_child']
const arr = [
  {
    name: "Baburam",
    relation: "self_owner"
  },
  {
    name: "Prapti",
    relation: "grand_child"
  },
  {
    name: "Sanjay",
    relation: "son"
  },
  {
    name: "Bhagwati",
    relation: "wife"
  },
  {
    name: "maya",
    relation: "mother"
  },
]
let sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => sortorder.indexOf(a.relation) - sortorder.indexOf(b.relation));
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an `order` array with the `relation` items in the order you need. Then use `indexOf` in the `sort` compare function

```js
const order = ["self_owner","wife","mother","son","grand_child"];
const arr = [{name:"Baburam",relation:"self_owner"},{name:"Prapti",relation:"grand_child"},{name:"Sanjay",relation:"son"},{name:"Bhagwati",relation:"wife"},{name:"maya",relation:"mother"},]

arr.sort((a,b) => order.indexOf(a.relation) - order.indexOf(b.relation))
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Code:

```js
const arr = [{name: "Baburam",relation: "self_owner"},{name: "Prapti",relation: "grand_child"},{name: "Sanjay",relation: "son"},{name: "Bhagwati",relation: "wife"},{name: "maya",relation: "mother"}]; 
const order = ['self_owner', 'wife', 'mother', 'son', 'grand_child'];

const result = order.reduce((a, c) => [...a, arr.find(user => user.relation === c)], []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a fixed array for your fixed sort order and then sort with its indexes,

```
const fixedOrder =['self_owner','wife','mother','son','grand_child']

const orderedArr=arr.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.fixedOrder.indexOf(a.relation) - b.fixedOrder.indexOf(a.relation);
});
```